# Python Protocols and Django Models

Tags: python, django, annotations, type-hinting

Suppose I have a simple protocol `A` and a class `B` which fails to implement that protocol:

```
from typing import Protocol

class A(Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> str: ...

class B:
    pass
```

Mypy will correctly complain when the code below is type checked

```
x: A = B()
```

```
mypy .
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "B", variable has type "A")
```

If however I have it so that `B` inherits from `django.db.models.Model` as follows

```
class A(Protocol):
    def foo(self) -> str: ...

class B(models.Model):
    pass


x: A = B()
```

mypy no longer throws an error when checking the line `x: A = B()`. I would have expected it to throw an error since `B` does not (seemingly) implement the `A` protocol. I assume this must have something to do with some inherited properties of `models.Model` which makes mypy think that the `foo` method is there.

Does anyone know what's going on here and have advice on how to have mypy check whether or not a Django model implements a protocol? Note that I would prefer that the model did not need to explicitly subclass the protocol.

Comment: You're missing `django-stubs` installed. To confirm, `reveal_type(models.Model)` to see `Any` in output.